# Pass an object as an argument in Java

Tags: java, object

I have this JavaScript code as an example:

```
function test (options) {
    console.log(options.firstName + " " + options.lastName);
}

const exampleObject = { firstName: "First", lastName: "Last"}
test(exampleObject);
// Output: "First Last"
```

Now, my question is, how can I do something similar to this in Java?

I want to pass an object `exampleObject` as an argument for a function/method.

Here's how it should look like, for example:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        test(/* Here, I want to pass the 'exampleObject' from above as an argument*/);
    }

    static void test (Object options) {
        System.out.println(options.firstName + " " + options.lastName);
        // Output should also be: "First Last"
    }
}
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: You'll need a class with two fields of `String`, `firstName` and `lastName`. This is quite Java 101 though, I'd suggest reading some introduction to the language first. And don't expect Java to behave nor to look like JavaScript, Java is to JavaScript what car is to carpet ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Java being strongly typed you will have to define a class where there are two fields defined for first and last name. The `Object` class is meant to the  be the root of the class hierarchy, every java class is a subclass of Object.

Here is a code example to achieve what you want.

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        test(new Person("first", "second"));
    }

    static void test (Person person) {
        System.out.println(person.first + " " + person.last);
        // Output should also be: "First Last"
    }

    private static class Person {
        public String first;
        public String last;

        public Person(String first, String last) {
            this.first = first;
            this.last = last;
        }
    }
}
```